# What does Android MediaRecorder.prepare() do?

Tags: android, mediarecorder

The [official Android documentation for `MediaRecorder.prepare()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#prepare()) says:

> Prepares the recorder to begin capturing and encoding data. This method must be called after setting up the desired audio and video sources, encoders, file format, etc., but before start().

What *exactly* does it do, and why do we need to call it before we start to capture media data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this function (prepare()) will be creates a random-access file stream to read from a file with the specified name and optionally write to a file.
This is required for stream processing. The stream process will not be started unless this function is used.
[see this doc.](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read the source code here: [MediaRecorder.java:833](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/MediaRecorder.java#833)

A glimpse of the code:

```
/**
 * Prepares the recorder to begin capturing and encoding data. This method
 * must be called after setting up the desired audio and video sources,
 * encoders, file format, etc., but before start().
 *
 * @throws IllegalStateException if it is called after
 * start() or before setOutputFormat().
 * @throws IOException if prepare fails otherwise.
 */
public void prepare() throws IllegalStateException, IOException
{
    if (mPath != null) {
        RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(mPath, "rws");
        try {
            _setOutputFile(file.getFD(), 0, 0);
        } finally {
            file.close();
        }
    } else if (mFd != null) {
        _setOutputFile(mFd, 0, 0);
    } else {
        throw new IOException("No valid output file");
    }

    _prepare();
}
```

And the native part of the code here: [mediarecorder.cpp](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/av/media/libmedia/mediarecorder.cpp#419)

```
status_t MediaRecorder::prepare()
{
    ALOGV("prepare");
    if (mMediaRecorder == NULL) {
        ALOGE("media recorder is not initialized yet");
        return INVALID_OPERATION;
    }
    if (!(mCurrentState & MEDIA_RECORDER_DATASOURCE_CONFIGURED)) {
        ALOGE("prepare called in an invalid state: %d", mCurrentState);
        return INVALID_OPERATION;
    }
    if (mIsAudioSourceSet != mIsAudioEncoderSet) {
        if (mIsAudioSourceSet) {
            ALOGE("audio source is set, but audio encoder is not set");
        } else {  // must not happen, since setAudioEncoder checks this already
            ALOGE("audio encoder is set, but audio source is not set");
        }
        return INVALID_OPERATION;
    }

    if (mIsVideoSourceSet != mIsVideoEncoderSet) {
        if (mIsVideoSourceSet) {
            ALOGE("video source is set, but video encoder is not set");
        } else {  // must not happen, since setVideoEncoder checks this already
            ALOGE("video encoder is set, but video source is not set");
        }
        return INVALID_OPERATION;
    }

    status_t ret = mMediaRecorder->prepare();
    if (OK != ret) {
        ALOGE("prepare failed: %d", ret);
        mCurrentState = MEDIA_RECORDER_ERROR;
        return ret;
    }
    mCurrentState = MEDIA_RECORDER_PREPARED;
    return ret;
}
```